# how to count array objects in nodejs/mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to count and get sorted elements in an array in `MongoDB` using `node js`. Can we do this without using aggregate?

```
{
   "schoolName":"mySchool",
   "isActive":true,
   "members":[
      {
         "status":"Accepted",
         "isAdmin":true
      },
      {
         "status":"Accepted",
         "isAdmin":true
      }
   ]
}
```

Here how to get elements to order by members size?

Comment: is this a nested array? a collection? a document? what do you mean by 'sorted' do you need to sort the array also?.

Comment: @DanStarns, this is a document, you can see it in the image.

Comment: Can you please post as code not image.

Comment: @funnydman      {
    "schoolName": "mySchool",
    "isActive": true,
    "members": [
        {
            "status": "Accepted",
            "isAdmin": true
        },
        {
            "status": "Accepted",
            "isAdmin": true
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using aggregation? AFAIK this can only achieved by using `$size` (and `$addFields`) in aggregation and it requires scanning the whole collection. Perhaps you should considering saving array lengths ahead of queries or simply storing members in a different collection.

Comment: @FrederickZhang, I don't want to avoid using aggregation, I just want to know the best way to do this.

Comment: @arpitbhatt027 Then basically I'd suggest you avoid using `$size` in queries/`$match` as it often requires a whole collection scan. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/

Comment: @FrederickZhang, thanks for the efforts, but this will give only the records which are matching the number passed inside. I am looking for the highest number of elements on the top.